# Convert WKT to EWKB/WKB using GDAL/OGR?

Tags: gdal, ogr, well-known-text, well-known-binary

How do I convert WKT geometry to EWKB/WKB?

Here's my WKT: `POLYGON ((113.749421064162419 62.38697568386327,113.754636282390067 62.386872575140529,113.755323673085357 62.334314115202005,113.67332998202032 62.334365618648548,113.669425138956726 62.334440650119198,113.671148294006684 62.384794727891922,113.671538735831803 62.387549090847621,113.749421064162419 62.38697568386327))`

And here's what I get using ogr's `feature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb()`:

`b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08@\\o\xf6\x83\xc4\xb6@O1\x88kQE\x1e@\\pK\xf5\xfaOb@O1\x85\n\xf9T@\\pW9\x1ar\xf5@O*\xca\xce\x0f\xb1 @\\k\x17\xd6\xa3\x0cc@O*\xcc~\x1a\x80L@\\j\xd7\xdc\x89\xbc\x1f@O*\xce\xf3\x83[\x83@\\j\xf4\x17\xf9a\x98@O1@\xf4!\xfc\t@\\j\xfa}\x9b\x19D@O1\x9b5gd}@\\o\xf6\x83\xc4\xb6@O1\x88kQE\x1e'`

The last thing seems corrupt and cannot be decoded with either ASCII  or UTF-8.

Is there any way to convert shapefile's geometry to EWKB/WKB other than with PostGIS (ogr, pyshp etc.)?

Comment: Binary is ***binary*** -- It **can't** be converted to UTF-8, only reformatted as hexadecimal, octal, or base64, but then it will no longer be binary,  only string.

Comment: @Vince Actually, this is exactly what I want. My goal is to compare this geometry to EWKB (hex?) representation from PostGIS. So how do I convert this byte output to hexadecimal (?) EWKT PostGIS form? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3) they say codec is needed anyway.

Comment: No, a codec is not needed. It's less than a dozen lines of code, but the question, "How do I format a binary array as hexadecimal ASCII?" Is off-topic for GIS SE (and probably already answered elaewhere).

Comment: Quick answer with Python: `from binascii import hexlify; hexlify(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03').decode()`